# Are null space of matrix and kernel function same?

Tags: svm, matrix, kernel-trick, image-processing, linear-algebra

I have recently started learning about machine learning and have come across kernels and null spaces. I understand that null space is the set of all vectors that satisfy the equation A.v = 0 (Where A is a matrix). I have been taught that null space is a set of vectors that are squished to 0 when transformation matrix A is applied. Then I came across SVM where kernel functions are used. I read that null spaces are also called kernels of a matrix. My questions are as follows.

1. Are both kernel functions and null spaces same?
2. What is the relation between kernel functions used in SVM and null space of matrix? Is this derived from the null space of  transformations used in SVM?
3. What is the reasoning behind kernels used in kernel convolution? For example: Is the Gaussian kernel used a representation of the transformation? How are they related to null spaces?

Could you please answer these questions? I am very confused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because there are multiple questions here. I have almost no understanding of SVMs, but I suspect you've unwittingly asked questions (2 and 3) that are very involved to answer.

Comment: I think so too. I have edited the question and updated it.

Comment: I think the question is fine (upvote)... never actually thought about the fact that one uses the same word for these two seemingly unrelated things...